# How to pipeline for document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection with documents like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b91035eca4f00000124e1d8"), "status" : 0, "date" : NumberLong(0), "players" : [ { "name" : "Valentin", "sets" : [ { "points" : [ { "score" : 0, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 0, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 0, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "sa" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 2, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 2, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 2, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 2, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 3,"comment" : "sw" }, { "score" : 3, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 3, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 4, "comment" : "sa" }, { "score" : 5, "comment" : "bh" }, { "score" : 5, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 5, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 6, "comment" : "fh" }, { "score" : 6, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 7, "comment" : "sw" }, { "score" : 7, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 7, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 8, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 8, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 9, "comment" : "bh" }, { "score" : 10, "comment" : "sw" }, { "score" : 11, "comment" : "sw" } ] } ] }, { "name" : "Zalupkin", "sets" : [ { "points" : [ { "score" : 0, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 1, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 2, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 2, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 3, "comment" : "fh"}, { "score" : 4, "comment" : "sw" }, { "score" : 5, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 6, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 7, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 8, "comment" : "sa" }, { "score" : 8, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 9, "comment" : "fh" }, { "score" : 10, "comment" : "sa" }, { "score" : 11, "comment" : "bh" }, {"score" : 11, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 12, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 13, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 13, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 13, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 14, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 15, "comment" : "sa" }, { "score" : 15, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 16, "comment" : "sw" }, { "score" : 16, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 17, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 18, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 18, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 19, "comment" : "sa" }, { "score" : 19, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 19, "comment" : "" }, { "score" : 19, "comment" : "" } ] } ] } ] }
```

I tried to make aggregation pipeline to count how mane comment "sw" have player with name "Valentin".

Also it's can be in many documents and I need to count whole comments.

Result must be something like this: { "_id" : null, "count" : 0 }

Thank you for assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
db.getCollection('test2').aggregate([
// Target only the documents which contains player Valentin

{ $match: {"players.name" : "Valentin"}},

//Unwind the array players so we can remove the part from the other players
{ $unwind: "$players"},

//Get the players whose name is Valentin of the unwind set
{ $match: {"players.name" : "Valentin"}},

//Reduce the deep of the array so we can count them well
{ $project: {"points": "$players.sets.points"}},
{ $unwind: "$points"},
{ $unwind: "$points"},

//Query of comment match
{ $match: {"points.comment" : "sw" }},

//Calculate count
{ $group: {
    _id: null,
    count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Why do you use multiple { $unwind: "$points"},

What's the secret? Without it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it does not. I am trying to use map to write other query.
The data we want to query is inside deep 3.
There are the array players, which contains the array sets which contains the array points.
In order to be able to filter which comments we want for a certain user, we need to unwind 3 times in order to reach the level where the comment is.
Anyway, I am sure it can be done in a more simple way, let me check out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation.

Initial [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter for matching player and 
next [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter points where comment = 'sw' followed by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to count matches in each point array. Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to perform the logic for all sets and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to calculate the all matches across all sets

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to count matches across all documents.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"players.name":"Valentin"}},
  {"$project":{
    "count":{
      "$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":{
            "$let":{
              "vars":{
                "mplayer":{
                  "$filter":{"input":"$players","as":"player","cond":{"$eq":["$$player.name","Valentin"]}
                 }
                }
              },
              "in":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$mplayer.sets",0]}
            }
          },
          "as":"set",
          "in":{
            "$size":{
              "$filter":{"input":"$$set.points","cond":{"$eq":["$$this.comment","sw"]}}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$group":{"_id":null,"count":{"$sum":"$count"}}}
])
```

Comment: 2018-09-06T12:49:51.672+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Missing 'in' parameter to $let",
        "code" : 16877,
        "codeName" : "Location16877"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:534:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:618:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1056:12
@(shell):1:1
>

Comment: Apologies. Updated now. Please give it another try.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!